# Connecting a VT100 terminal to Redhat Linux

Tags: rhel, terminal-emulator

I have the following Linux box: 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikan ga) x86
I'm trying to connect to it, using a Mainframe integration product which supports only the VT100 protocol. 
I can connect successfully from TinyTerm using Wyse60 settings but when using VT100 settings the screen comes up messed up. 
How can I configure my Redhat box to support VT100 ?

Answer (score 1):

Wyse60 is a completely different command set from the basic VT100-compatible ANSI command set that' used e.g. on the linux console or by xterm etc. so you probably have the correct terminfo files installed and have set the `TERM` environment variable to the correct value (probably `wy60` I guess) when using TinyTerm (which I'm unfamiliar with).

When using the terminal emulator that only supports basic VT100 mode, you will need to set `TERM=vt100` in the environment:

```
$ export TERM=vt100
```

That will lead to programs wanting to address the screen to use a file `/usr/share/terminfo/v/vt100` to determine the capabilities, so check whether that file exists. It should be part of the `ncurses` package.

If there happens to be a `TERMCAP` environment setting, then you should unset that.

Things like colorized `ls` output depends on `LS_COLORS` in the environment. As vt100 doesn't have colors, unset that as wel..